# Correct event listener for Javascript in input field for Ajax Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

What I want to happen is that after the member is selected, the province, town, and barangay will be automatically inputed but I want to add another listener for the province to do another query for shipping method but my code is not working in

```
$("#member_id").change(function () {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '/panel/admin/members/search_id',
        data:{'search':value},
        success:function(data){
            //console.log(data);
            $("#loading_member").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loading_member").css("display", "none");
                $('#province').val(data.province);
                $('#city_town').val(data.city_num);
                $('#brgy').val(data.brgy);
                $('#member_code').val(data.member_code);
            },500);
        } 
    });
});
```

this part is not working and I do not know is the exact to use.

```
const provincelist = document.querySelector('#province');

provincelist.addEventListener('provincelist', updateValue);

function updateValue() {
    var value=$('#province').val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'get',
        url : '{{route("panel.admin.search_province")}}',
        data:{'search':value},
        success:function(data){
            $("#loading_shipping").css("display", "block");
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#loading_shipping").css("display", "none");
                $('#shipping_method').find('option').remove().end();
                $('#shipping_method').append(data);
            },500);
        } 
    });
    console.log(value);
}
```

Is this the correct way to do? I just want to do another ajax query every time the `$('#province').val(data.province)` has a value.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please note the text on the tag [tag:javascript-events] which says "DO NOT USE THIS TAG"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest:

`provincelist.addEventListener('change', updateValue);`

The first argument is the event name and the second is the callback to execute when the event occurs. `'provincelist'` is not a known event. See [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener).

Now, the event are firing from the user actions. If the value of `#province` changed programmatically like in the first Ajax succes callback, there will be no `change` event. But you can call the `updateValue()` function right after the value has changed.

```
success:function(data){
   //console.log(data);
   $("#loading_member").css("display", "block");
   setTimeout(function(){
   $("#loading_member").css("display", "none");
   $('#province').val(data.province);
   $('#city_town').val(data.city_num);
   $('#brgy').val(data.brgy);
   $('#member_code').val(data.member_code);
   updateValue();  // <-------------- Call the second Ajax here
 },500);
```

}

Comment: I will try now.. Thank you